# abby fine reader page layout

Tags: scanner, ocr

I have to scan and ocr an entire book using abby fine reader.

do you know how can i define a zone of interest to scan all the pages of the book? I don;t wish to scan and recognize (header, footer, page numbers of the books)

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it:

- make a recognition area for one page
- save the selection: Area->Save area template.
- select all the pages
- load the previous saved selection: Area->Load Area template